# Wordpress plugin that inserts the link of the previous post in post_content

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress plugin that inserts the link of the previous post in post_content, I'm not able to do, I already followed all the methods taught in forums, here in the stack I get several, but always inserted a link to the same post today! the link only takes the user to the same current post! it's as if I refresh the page by clicking the link, I made a plugin that takes the person to the category page of the post, but it's not good for SEO. So I need to build links to the post.
.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin name: HAW ADD URL POST CONTENT
Plugin URI: https://mywebsite.com
Description: This is a plugin to auto inser internal link to post_content(READ THE README.TXT) 
*/
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'add_string_on_publish_link' , '999', 3 );
function add_string_on_publish_link( $data,  $postarr='' ){
....... codes
$myvalueX = "{$arr[0]} {$arr[1]} {$arr[2]}";
$tag = "{$arr[0]} {$arr[1]}";
$tagX = implode('-',explode(' ', $tag));
$urlsite = site_url();
$bar = '/';
//THE_ARIAN BEGIN
//$prev_post = previous_post_link( '%link', __( '&larr; %title', 'text-domain' ) );

//$prev_post = get_adjacent_post(false, '', true);
//if(!empty($prev_post)) {
//$prevpost = '<a href="' . get_permalink($prev_post->ID) . '" title="' . $prev_post->post_title . '">' . $prev_post->post_title . '</a>'; }

  //$prevpost = previous_post_link( '%link');

    //$prevpost = previous_post_link( '%link', TRUE); 

  //$prevpost = get_previous_post('%link');

  //$prevpost= get_previous_posts_link();

  //$prevpost = get_previous_posts_page_link();
//THE_ARIAN END
$urlcatbase = get_option( 'category_base' );
$urlcatbaseX = "<a href=".$urlsite.$bar.$urlcatbase.$bar.$tagX.">".$tag."</a>";
//$urltagbaseX = "<a href=".$prevpost.">".$tag."</a>";   //THE_ARIAN
 $data['post_content'] .= "<p>{$data['post_title']} {mycontent}{$urlcatbaseX}</p>";
$data['post_content'] = preg_replace('/[\s]{1,}/',' ', $data['post_content']);
.......codes
}
```

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your code should do, however there is a dedicated function to get previous post link:

get_previous_posts_link

you may use it like that:

```
echo get_previous_posts_link('Prev post or any other label');
```

Comment: So, this is regular WP function to achieve this kind of functionality. You commented it, ok, I didn't saw it. You have to provide more code and explain your goal if you want to get help.

Comment: The purpose is of course, this code uses wp_insert_post_data to insert a link in post_content, it already works, 100% of the code is already in my post, the code of the hidden part, is to do other actions .... I repeat, this code already is working 100%, but I'm inserting a link to cat pages, the code is complete for everyone here. I want to insert link from the previous post, the code already works as it is in the post above, and my goal reached is clear in the post as well. Thank you.